# Is it meaningful to talk about single-event frequentist probabilities?

Tags: probability, confidence-interval

When learning about confidence intervals, we are told that we must not talk about "the probability that the true value lies within the interval" because (frequentist) probability is the limit of frequencies in a mostly-fictional population of experiments, and has nothing to say about whether a fixed value lies in a fixed interval.  (Except, perhaps, to unhelpfully say that it is either 0 or 1.)

Nitpicky note: I am aware that if we consider the confidence interval to be a random variable then a useful probability statement can be made about it - but whenever I calculate one from real-world data, I seem to get a fixed interval and not a random variable. :D

But...

1 in every 100 million people have the brain-exploding flu.  A man is tested for BEF - with a test that is 99% accurate in both directions - and the test results come up positive.  The man asks his doctor if he really has brain-exploding flu.

I feel like the doctor should be able to say "almost certainly not".  Just eyeballing it, the probability is about 1 in a million here... or is it?  Doesn't the same objection apply?  This is also a single event, and whether the man has BEF is an unknown but fixed value.

Comment: "a test that is 99% accurate in both directions" - what does this mean exactly?

Comment: @Aksakal 99% sensitivity/specificity I presume.

Answer (score 4):

In your example, the test does not tell us the risk of disease. It makes a decision. It is either a true positive, true negative, false positive, or false negative. The doctor, in trying to explain the test, would tell the patient that the results were a false positive. The patient, not having died from the disease, is a living testament to the imperfection of that diagnosis. Diagnostic tests are unconcerned with ascribing a single event probability risk.

In medicine, we differentiate between *diagnostic tests* and *risk predictions*. Risk predictions use a patient's risk profile to construct an time-interval based risk prediction given you are at-risk for disease at that time. For instance, the Gail model predicts 5 year breast cancer risk in a woman who is free of breast cancer and has both of her breasts (no mastectomy; no breast tissue=no cancer risk). Age, menopausal status, family history, and other risk factors are reported. The model gives a percentage breast cancer risk. This percentage is used to counsel the patient and advise preventative options.

A Bayesian interpretation of 5 year breast cancer risk is readily accepted. A frequentist relies on the concept of potential outcomes. These are like counterfactual inference. We presume women who are otherwise similar in their risk profile pose a type of superpopulation whose frequency of 5 year breast cancer incidence is concordant with the risk prediction.

Comment: I don't think the doctor should say the results are a false positive because we are not that certain.  If you do think there's a threshold below which probabilities may be rounded down to zero, then modify my example so the probability is just above that cutoff.  I also don't think the patient's failure to die before the test results are in is dispositive - there are diseases which incubate for a while before making their presence felt.  Finally, if it's legitimate to treat a woman as representative of a superpopulation, why can't we do the same with confidence intervals?

Comment: Just to hammer the point home, suppose the test for brain-exploding flu works by providing a 99% confidence interval for the number of pathogens in the patient's body, which is either (-infinity,0] or [1,infinity).  Following a positive result, the true value lies in the interval if and only if the patient has the disease.  Can we really deny that the first has a probability and also inform the patient of the probability of the second?

Comment: @MarkBoyd Since BEF is not real, I assumed a person died immediately after contracting it. If they are alive, they did not get it.

Answer (score 1):

This would fall under the philosophy of probability imo. I would suggest you start with the [SEP entry on interpretations of probability](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/probability-interpret/#FreInt) and then possibly continue with following the references therein.

Answer (score 1):

The concepts are diagonal to each other in a contingency table.

**A frequentist probability is** the probability (/frequency) that a test or interval fails/succeeds. That is, the probability that a test says positive when we are healthy/sick, and/or the probability that a test says negative when we are sick/healthy.

$$ \begin{align}
&sick& healthy&\quad sum\\
negative \quad&\color{green}{99}& \color{red}{99 \, 999 \, 999} &\quad 100 \, 000 \,098\\
positive\quad &\color{red}1& \color{green}{9\,899\,999 \,901} & \quad 9\,899\,999 \,902  \\
sum \quad& 100 & 9\, 999\, 999\, 900 & \quad \color{blue}{100\, 000\, 000\, 000}
\end{align}$$

It is the sum of the red sections divided by the blue section. $$\frac{\color{red}1 + \color{red}{99 \, 999 \, 999} }{\color{blue}{100\, 000\, 000\, 000}} = 0.01$$

Which contrast with the sum of the green sections divided by the blue section.

$$\frac{\color{green}{99} + \color{green}{9 \, 899 \, 999 \, 901} }{\color{blue}{100\, 000\, 000\, 000}} = 0.99$$

Note that these are relating to the columns of the 2x2 contingency table (both have ratios 1:99 and 99:1).

---

**A Bayesian probability is** the probability that a given estimate is true. 
$$ \begin{align}
&sick& healthy&\quad sum\\
negative \quad&99& {99 \, 999 \, 999} &\quad 100 \, 000 \,098\\
positive\quad &\color{red}1& \color{green}{9\,899\,999 \,901} & \quad \color{blue}{9\,899\,999 \,902}  \\
sum \quad& 100 & 9\, 999\, 999\, 900 & \quad {100\, 000\, 000\, 000}
\end{align}$$given a particular outcome.

Note that these are relating to the rows of the 2x2 table. And, they are not the same as the frequentist's probabilities.

### ----------------------------

In words:

**Frequentist:**

If we are healthy,

- then a failure is a test outcome telling us we are sick,

And if we are sick,

- then a failure is a test outcome telling us we
  are healthy.

This can be different than the probability that a certain outcome (test/interval) is true or not.

**Bayesian:**

If we have a test outcome telling us that we are sick then either we are either

- sick and the test was right. Or,
- not sick and the test was wrong.

The probability of these two situations, which Bayesian techniques answer (using prior information), do not follow directly from frequentist probabilities.

### ----------------------------

Since we know about the 1 in 100 million (prior knowledge) we can say: In the case of a positive test result... much more often will there be patients with false negatives (1% of 99 999 999 in 100 million) than true positives (99% of 1 in 100 million), and thus one can not say that the probability is 99% that the test result is right (yet, still the test is 1% wrong, namely 1% wrong in the 99 999 999 out of 100 million truly negative cases, and 1% wrong in the 1 out of 100 million truly positive cases ).

Comment: Frequentists are allowed to take the prior information into account here - they just call it the base rate.  And if they calculate the frequency at which the test is wrong when it says positive, they'll get the same answer as the Bayesians.  The question is: can they then answer the single-event question the patient wants answered ("What is the probability that *I* have the disease?")  and if they can, why can't we do the same for confidence intervals?

Comment: A frequentist method (I believe it is wrong to speak about frequentists as if this is a property of people), does not calculate *'the frequency at which the test is wrong when it says positive'*, instead it calculates *'the frequency at which the test is wrong when it you are sick/healthy'*. A frequentist method looks at the columns, a Bayesian method looks at the rows. The advantage of a frequentist method is that it does not need to calculate the row and columns sums, but it addresses a different question, so: No there is not a single-event frequentist probability. It is a different concept.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Also "frequentist" and "fictional" come together naturally only in social sciences. (Physicist [Lev Landau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lev_Landau) [joked](https://ru.wikiquote.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2_%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%83) that there are three types of sciences: natural, unnatural and antinatural).

You don't need to use a word Bayes even once in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.1623.pdf) 19 pp paper to come up with a significance number for a single event: Observation of a first $\nu_\tau$ candidate in the OPERA experiment in the CNGS beam, N. Agafonova et al. (OPERA Collaboration) arXiv:1006.1623 [hep-ex]

It's a rather technical article in high energy physics, so in this case it's Ok to jump to Conclusions section (pun intended):

> The observation of one possible tau candidate in the decay channel
>   $h^-(\pi^0)\nu_\tau$ has a significance of 2.36 $\sigma$ of not being
>   a background fluctuation. If one considers all decay modes included in
>   the search the significance of the observation becomes 2.01 $\sigma$.
>   The expected number of $\nu_\tau$ events detected in the analysed sample is
>   0.54 $\pm$ 0.13(syst.)